# API for best gas prices, like GasBuddy?

Tags: web-services, api

Is there a web services API to get the gas prices based on address, zip code, or GPS coordinates? I have been unable to find one which is reliable and available freely. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that the gas price is such a popular topic that the different gas price providers agreed upon a special API for it. I would assume each web service has a different one (if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well check out www.mygasfeed.com and they are releasing an API. But they need a community to help them report gas prices.

pretty interesting web app that users can see gas stations visually on a map.